# VIM: omnicomplete popup menu has incomplete message

Tags: vim, vi, popupmenu, youcompleteme

I'm using `YouCompleteMe` library into `vim` to autocomplete my code.

I have an issue for `vim popup menu` as shown in the image below the `addEventListener` method in `javascript` has long description here but it get cut because of my screen bound. is there any way to scroll horizontally to read the missing part like I do when I'm scrolling vertically `<c-n>` for down and `<c-p>` for up. Is there is any short key for moving right and left on `vim popup menu` or any other way to achieve that.

[image: Screenshot of incomplete description]

Answer (score 1):

1. No, there's no way to achieve that in Vim's current state.
2. Vim already has a perfectly working way to display extensive documentation in the preview window during completion so your plugin is misusing the completion menu.

   You should either tell its author to use the completion menu properly or find a better one.

   From `:help 'completeopt'`:

   ```
   preview  Show extra information about the currently selected
            completion in the preview window.  Only works in
            combination with "menu" or "menuone".
   ```

Comment: 3. Relying on completion for API discovery is a gross anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to raise this issue to the author and looking for a new one for time being. Thanks!